# how to get rolling last 5 months in netezza

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I am simply trying to get the rolling 12 months in netezza and i can't seem to find any good solution so far..

```
  Contract      SpendDate     Expenses
    sfd6s        2016205       8765
    axy12        2016206       1320
    axy12        2016307       12980
    axy12        2016308       1260
    axy12        2016309       1200
    rhg65        2016410       7800
    fdhju        2016411       300
```

here is how my query look like:

```
select contract, spendDate, expenses 
from myTable
```

here is the trick, the spendDate format is like this:

```
Year + Quarter + Month
```

so the middle number after the year is the quarter which is either 1, 2, 3 or 4. So in my query, i want to say give the rolling 12 months from today. Please help.
here is my desired results:

```
 Contract      SpendDate     Expenses
    axy12        2016206       1320
    axy12        2016307       12980
    axy12        2016308       1260
    axy12        2016309       1200
    rhg65        2016410       7800
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Be clear on what your expecting... speicify sample input and desired output..

Comment: i updated my question and added the desired results.  I just want to get the last rolling 5 months.  please see the updated questions.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date to transform your spendDate into a normal date, and then normal date math on it.

```
select contract, spendDate, expenses 
from  mytable
where to_date(spendDate,'YYYYQMM') 
    between add_months(date_trunc('month',current_date),-5)  
    and add_months(date_trunc('month',current_date),-1)
order by spendDate
;

 CONTRACT | SPENDDATE | EXPENSES 
----------+-----------+----------
 axy12    |   2016206 |     1320
 axy12    |   2016307 |    12980
 axy12    |   2016308 |     1260
 axy12    |   2016309 |     1200
 rhg65    |   2016410 |     7800
(5 rows)
```

Comment: @moe does this solution do what you want?